How to center my elements in center (top, bottom, left and right)?
i have a home page having the following :
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import Link from "next/link";

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <main className="flex flex-col justify-center h-full  text-center  max-w-5xl mx-auto gap-6">
      <h1 className="text-5xl font-bold">Invoicipedia</h1>
      <p>
        <Button asChild>
          <Link href="/dashboard">Login</Link>
        </Button>
      </p>
    </main>
  );
}

when i run it i got my elements in center just between right and left :

however i want my elements to be center r
howver i would like my elements to be center (left, right AND top and bottom), how can i do that please ?
P.S: my goal is to be like the following :


Try this :
By adding the h-screen and items center
main classname : "flex flex-col justify-center items-center h-screen text-center max-w-5xl mx-auto gap-6"
Also text-center is always for text, but here we are dealing with the boxes or elements
text-center: This class to centers text within its container. If your goal is to center all child elements (like buttons or boxes), using items-center is more appropriate because it centers the flex items along the cross axis.

You have applied h-full to your <main> tag, but that is only relative to its wrapping <div>, which is not full-height.
You need to make your document body and Next.js wrapping container full-height too. Add the following to your tailwind.css:
html, body, #__next {
  height: 100%;
}

Note: If you want to make it more flexible, use min-h-full instead of h-full on your <main> element. This way, content will be vertically centered when there's little content but page will still grow normally if needed.
